How to split a variable?
I have one string variable which has 4 characters: the first two are the hours and the second two are the minutes. How can I split that variable into two variables, one for the hours and the other for the minutes?
I tried the commands recode and split, but I don´t know how to use them right.

Neither of those commands can help. This may help. If you want more specific help, please expand your question using a data example and code.
clear
input str4 given 
"1234"
"2359"
end 

gen hr = real(substr(given, 1, 2))

gen min = real(substr(given, 3, 2))

gen double time = clock(given, "hm")
format time %tcHH:MM

list 

     +--------------------------+
     | given   hr   min    time |
     |--------------------------|
  1. |  1234   12    34   12:34 |
  2. |  2359   23    59   23:59 |
     +--------------------------+


